# Does a creature with dethrone trigger Kami of Celebration?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I couldn't find anything saying in which order these things happen. So, for example, say I'm attacking my opponent with the highest life total with a couple unmodified creatures while [Marchesa, the Black Rose](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Marchesa%2C%20the%20Black%20Rose) and [Kami of Celebration](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kami%20of%20Celebration) are on the field. Marchesa makes all of these creatures modified, but does that happen in time for it to cause Kami to impulse draw?

Answer (score 3):

**No**

What happens is you attack, Marchesa triggers. Kami of Celebration would also trigger now, if you were attacking with any modified creatures. But you aren't attacking with any modified creatures. By the time the Marchesa triggers resolve, you are no longer declaring attackers, and it is too late for Kami of Celebration to trigger.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these triggers apply their check at the same time, when a creature attacks. So the counter from dethrone is not there yet for the Kami's ability to see it.

> 603.2. Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability
> automatically triggers. The ability doesn’t do anything at this point.

Note: The counter from dethrone can trigger abilities such as "Whenever a modified creature deals combat damage to a player ...". Currently only [this](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2Fwhenever+%28a%7Cone+or+more%29+modified+creatures%3F+%28you+control+%29%3Fdeals%3F+%28combat+%29%3Fdamage%2F&unique=cards&as=checklist&order=name&dir=asc) creature has that ability.

Comment: Thanks! That clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

Dethrone is a triggered ability, and when the condition for a triggered ability is met, that doesn't cause the effect of the ability, it just causes the ability to go on the stack. It's only when that ability resolves that the effect is applied. You can choose in what order your triggered abilities are checked, but all of the trigger abilities are checked before any of them resolve. Once all of them are checked and the ones whose conditions were met are put on the stack, then the normal steps of the stack are applied (players get priority, if all pass the topmost effect resolves, etc.). Whether the creature is modified is checked at the time it's declared as an attacker, so by the time the Dethrone ability resolves, it's no longer being declared as an attacker.

However, the whole point of Marchesa is that if you attack with a creature, it either dies (and then it comes back at the end of the turn), or it survives, and then next turn it does have the +1/+1 counter before it's declared as an attacker, and it will trigger Kami. You can combine this with other "when attacks" triggers and/or ETB triggers. If the creature dies, then its ETB triggers at the end of the turn, and if it doesn't die, then next turn you get the Kami trigger. With the right creatures (such as [Aether Channeler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aether%20Channeler)), you can be guaranteed card advantage either way. With something like [Archon of Cruelty](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archon%20of%20Cruelty), you're actually better off with it dying.